# How to save as text file as UTF-8 encoding from word doc using VBA?

Tags: vba, utf-8, ms-word

I have created a VBA macros for html conversion. After the conversion process, the word document should save as ".txt" file with UTF-8 encoding in the same path and same file name, when i click the command button.

Is it possible to make it?

Comment: What's your code so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the appropriate parameters to the `SaveAs` method:

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs _
    FileName:="C:\My\Path\Textfile.txt", _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatText, _
    Encoding:=65001
```

Comment: it is working good. but the macro should be saved in the active document path. For e.g.: The txt file should be saved into e:\mypath\document-foder, when i am working in e: drive. It should be saved into z:\mypath\document-foder, when i am working in z: drive.